# parsing XML with special characters

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Has the question above stated, I'm trying to parse a string that has a xml on it. I'm using the classes XDocument and XElement to parse the information that is on the XML into a Dictionary. The code looks something like this:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString); 
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach(XElement x in xDoc.Root.Descendants())
{
    temp.Add(x.Name.ToString(),x.Value.ToString());
}
```

**xmlString is the string that have the xml content

This usually works fine, except when the xmlString has some kind of special character ('>', '<', '&') on a tag. For example when something like this appears:

```
<Content> #include <stdio.h> </Content>
```

I assumed that the code that I implemented doesn't work on this case since C# looks at what he believe is an XML tag has should be seen has plain text. Basically, my question is  how can i manage to parse this kind of XML that contain special characters has the one i stated before?

Comment: if you have access to the feed then htmlencode the values of the xml before you output it

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: That is not XML; XML defines '>', '<', '&' as metacharacters and that is not what you have. `XDocument` only works on XML, you have to get whatever is sending the string to send XML.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, 
you are trying to parse an invalid xml.

If you can, I would recommend you to fix the code which PRODUCES this xml and make it valid.

If you cant, you need to write/use a function, which will convert these special characters to their encoded variants.